# angularjs ng-include does not reload when history back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have written a script which dynamically changes the `ng-include` source and loads a different template based on URL's with a hash (#).

Example links are:

```
example.com/test#template-1.html
example.com/test#template-2.html
```

Is there a way for `ng-include` to reload the template when the history back button is clicked. I do not wish to make use of `ng-route` at this point. I just need to know if there is a way to do this with `ng-include`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
      " **onbeforeunload** " event
in your javascript and set the value for your ng-include variable.